# Sockets.io build error, fatal error c1083, please advise

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to unpack a nodejs module socket.io. I was getting a build error to install Visual stdio 2005 and .net framework2 sdk, so I did. now I am getting the following error with no advice on how to fix it. please help me.

I am using vista, 32 bit.

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.8.18 (ia32) and NPM

```
    C:\Users\shane>CD C:\nodefiles


C:\NodeFiles>npm install socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options

> ws@0.4.25 install C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-c
lient\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\w
s>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\sock
et.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\sock
et.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
socket.io@0.9.13 node_modules\socket.io
├── base64id@0.1.0
├── policyfile@0.0.4
├── redis@0.7.3
└── socket.io-client@0.9.11 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obf
uscator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.25)

C:\NodeFiles>npm install socket.io
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\NodeFiles>npm install socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander

> ws@0.4.25 install C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-c
lient\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\w
s>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
C:\Users\shane\.node-gyp\0.8.18\deps\uv\include\uv.h(55): fatal error C1083: Ca
nnot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory [C:\NodeFiles\nod
e_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding
.sln]
Project : warning PRJ0018: The following environment variables were not found:
[C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules
\ws\build\binding.sln]
C:\Users\shane\.node-gyp\0.8.18\deps\uv\include\uv.h(55): fatal error C1083: Ca
nnot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory [C:\NodeFiles\nod
e_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding
.sln]
Project : warning PRJ0018: The following environment variables were not found:
[C:\NodeFiles\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules
\ws\build\binding.sln]
socket.io@0.9.13 node_modules\socket.io
├── base64id@0.1.0
├── policyfile@0.0.4
├── redis@0.7.3
└── socket.io-client@0.9.11 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obf
uscator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.25)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with 2008 trying to install node-serialport, so I installed Visual C++ Studio Express 2010
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express

I used the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" to run "npm install" worked like a charm.